# How to set Elixir 1.6 formatter to add 2 new lines between module functions?

Tags: elixir, formatter

Is there ability to configure `.formatter.exs` so formatter does 2 new lines between functions in module?
Example:

```
@spec start_link(String.t()) :: {:error, String.t()} | {:ok, pid()}
def start_link(url) do
   Agent.start_link(fn -> %Links{url: url, remaining: [url]} end)
end
# 2 lines
# 
@spec has_more_links?(pid()) :: boolean()
def has_more_links?(agent_pid) do
   length(get_remaining_links(agent_pid)) > 0
end
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't supported at the moment. The [documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#format_string!/2) says:

> The formatter respects the input format in some cases. Those are
> listed below:
>
> - ...
> - Newlines inside blocks are kept as in the input
>   except for: 1) expressions that take multiple lines will always have
>   an empty line before and after and 2) **empty lines are always
>   squeezed together into a single empty line**
> - ...